# Magento 2.3 : Shipping Address Form Inline During Checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.3.0, shipping-step

Shipping Address Form Inline During Checkout

I'm currently trying to customize the checkout process of Magento 2.3.0, and am wondering how to make the shipping address form inline when adding a second address (instead of the popup form).

I got a variable `isFormInline`, If I set it to `true` from shipping.js then it will open the form always on checkout shipping address with inline.

If I put this in a method `onShippingAddressChanges` with the condition of new address and set `isFormInline = 1`, But its not getting impact.

Can you please help me out on this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please post your js code?

Comment: Hi @ashish, did you get any solution for this?